# How to obtain the request headers that was sent after I get or post a request to the endpoint

Tags: python, cookies, header, python-requests

How do I retrieve one of the parameters that's generated in the requests header? I need it in order to maintain the session.

[image]

For example I need the cookie parameter that's generated in the requests header.

Comment: `r.request.headers` where `r` is the response object.

Comment: right, that gives me the response headers, but I want the request headers

Comment: `r.request.headers` contains the request headers,  `r.headers` contains the response headers.

Comment: I see. Thanks for the clarification. But for some reason it doesn't give me all the request headers and it skips over the part that I actually need.

{'user-agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_14_3) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/72.0.3626.121 Safari/537.36', 'Accept-Encoding': 'gzip, deflate', 'Accept': '*/*', 'Connection': 'keep-alive'}

Comment: Those are the request headers, assuming you changed the default User-Agent. If you just want the cookies you can use `r.cookies` (it's a CookieJar object but you can get a gictionary with `r.cookies.get_dict()`). If you want `requests` to store and use cookies you can use a [`Session()`](http://docs.python-requests.org/en/master/api/#request-sessions) object.

Comment: There seems to be actually more to the request headers in the picture I posted than I got from the r.request.headers, any idea why? Also, I don't think it's a standard cookie as r.cookies doesn't return the same thing

Comment: That's because `requests` is just an HTTP client, not a browser. Cookies may be created from JavaScript or actions you performed. If you can't make it work with a Session you may have to use Selenium.